# dss is showing invalid date format,i think it is abug in dss

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

```
my input mappings are two that is workid and modifiedon(data type is time stamp i selected in input mappings) while i am running at try this service it is showing error in dss server side like below
```

Nested Exception:-
java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid date format (2012-03-14 00:00:00+05:30) with out - s at correct place

same query is running fine in postgres sql,i dnt know whats wrong in dss,data type is not supporting in dss,i think it is abug in dss.

Answer (score 4):

Use the date in following format.

2012-03-14T00:00:00+05:30

or

2012-03-14T00:00:00

Comment: first we have to convert into epoch time then only dss will work and input mapping we have to change the data type as BIGINT,i done R&D and finally i succeed.

Comment: lakmali-erandi your answer is wrong,first we have to convert into epoch time then only dss is working so,it mean dss support date format in that way,u have to give input mapping as BIGINT as data type yesterday i done R&D and finally i succed,

Comment: Please note that you had mentioned your input mapping data type is timestamp. For such an input mapping the format I have provided workes properly without any issue. I checked this before posting. I could reproduce the problem with your date format. The date formats provided by me worked with out that problem. Hence this answer is not wrong. What was the error you were getting with my suggestions?